# C# XNA Loading in textures

Tags: c#, xna, textures

I have having alot of issues loading in textures into my simple game. First off, I am able to load in a texture when im inside of "Game1.cs". However, I am currently trying to create a level. So I want to load in all the pictures in the Level class.

```
public Level(IServiceProvider _serviceProvider)
{
    content = new ContentManager(_serviceProvider, "Content");
    mNrOfTextures = 3;
    mTextures[] = new Texture2D[mNrTextures];
    mTextures[0] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("sky");
    //And then more textures and other stuff..
}
```

But the program can never find the file sky. I dont really get any useful error messages and im moving away from any tutorials currently. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Full path to file: C:\c++\ProjIV\ProjIV\ProjIVContent\

Comment: I usually pass the contentmanager in from game1.cs to take full advantage of caching, but I'm guessing you've confirmed that your "sky" texture is in the Content folder?

Comment: It's been forever since I've done any XNA but I see you're using the static `Content` instead of your instance of `ContentManager`. Is that right?

Comment: Full path to file: C:\c++\ProjIV\ProjIV\ProjIVContent\
edit; ive tried changing it around but seemed to fail on every attempt.

Comment: Also guessing `mTextures[ = ...` should be `mTextures = new Texture2D[mNrTextures];`?

Comment: Thats just me typing the code manually from looking from my laptop onto stationary. Fixed.

Comment: @413X - I figured. What about the using `Content` instead of `content`? You create a `ContentManager`, but then you don't use it.

Comment: If im totally honest. Im watching various of example projects, trying to piece this together and just assume it did something magical. It is the way it was written in another project where it works. Changing Content-> content. Does not work. I had some issues earlier about finding the correct folder for the contents. For example, when i loaded in a textfile. I had to do; const string path =  "../../../../ProjIVContent/Level.txt"

Answer (score 0):

I personally just pass my `ContentManager` to my level class, instead of passing the service provider as others do.

In this case, you need to use your local `content` instance, not the static `Content`

```
 mTextures[0] = content.Load<Texture2D>("sky");
```

EDIT: I see this did not work, can you attach a picture of your solution layout with the content?

Comment: Your content path should NOT be `../../../`, it should just be `"Content"`. `../` goes back a directory. So what you are doing is probably going _back_ from your `.exe` to your project's content directory. Instead you need to go _forward_ into the `Content` directory generated when you compile.